# ggplot2 scale_y_continuous setting limits removes datapoints

Tags: r, ggplot2

I just noticed how ggplot is removing datapoints when the scale_y_continuous is limited so that certain values are not included. Example:

```
library("ggplot2")
exdf <- mtcars

ggp <- ggplot(data=exdf, mapping=aes(x=cyl, y=disp)) + 
    stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="point", size=4) + 
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(1, 400))
ggp 

#compare to: 
range(exdf$disp)
ggp <- ggplot(data=exdf, mapping=aes(x=cyl, y=disp)) + 
    stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="point", size=4) + 
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(1, 500))
ggp
```

All three dots are displayed and are not limited by the range, but the underlying data-range is limited. Note the messages about "rows containing non-finite values". I find this behavior odd and wonder if there might be a workaround?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by _workaround_? Please elaborate on your desired behavior.

Comment: You could use coord_cartesian to limit plot rather than scale_y_continuous limits.

Comment: I want the values to be NOT exclude in the calculation of the stat_sumary, at the same time, I want to limit my y-axis at will.

Comment: I think ggplot is forcing you to do the right thing here: excluding points from the plot but including them in the summary is … wrong, and in fact dishonest. There may be situations where it’s legitimate (can’t think of any) but in general it’s not something you should do.

Comment: @Nick F: That worked! Thank you.

Comment: @Konrad: Not sure if I catch your drift here, do you mean that limiting an axis in a plot to a data-range that this narrower than the actual databasis is deceiving? Even if the plot containts something like errorbars?

Comment: @vanaoveneri In general yes, that’s what I mean. Even if error bars are given the actual points corresponding to outliers are informative, and leaving them out may give the false impression that no outliers exist.

Comment: Fair point. I'll keep that in mind.